# LISP: Force evaluation

Tags: list, lisp, quote

I'm taking a list name as input with a single quote ('), but after doing a few operations, I want to actually evaluate it instead of treat it as an atom.

So for example, just for simplicity sake, I have the following list:

```
(setf LT '(A B C))
```

I have a function called `SEP`. To run the function, I must run it as `(SEP 'LT)`. So as you can see, LISP will interpret `LT` as an atom instead of evaluate it as a list, which is not what I want.

So essentially, I want `(SEP 'LT)` to really become `(SEP '(A B C))` somehow.

The input format can't be changed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `LT` is a top-level variable, defined with `defvar`, then you can get its value with `symbol-value` as such:

```
* (symbol-value 'lt)
(A B C)

* (defun sep (name)
    (assert (symbolp name))
    (let ((value (symbol-value name)))
      ...
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  (btw, I think it's `symbolp` not `symbol-p`)

Comment: `(assert (symbolp name))` -> `(check-type name symbol)`.